# Keeping a CSS attribute after an animation is completely finished

Tags: html, css

I need help with this project.  When I hover over the `textarea`, the box expands:

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}
p {
  font-family: Sans-Serif;
  color:white;
}
@keyframes do {
  to {width: 500px; height: 100px;}
}
@keyframes undo {
  to {width: 50px; height: 50px}
}
#entering {
  animation-name: undo;
  animation-duration: .5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  text-align: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: none;
  font-family: Times;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
 resize: none;
 overflow: hidden; 
}
/* The animation-fill-mode doesn't keep 
 * the width attribute for the zoom out
 * animation above.
 */
#entering:hover {
  animation-name: do;
  animation-duration: .5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
#text {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id = "text">
<textarea id = "entering">SAMPLE
</textarea>
</div>
<p>An example of my project.</p>
```

However, I want to make it so that after the animation is completely finished, the `height` and `width` attributes stay the same so the `undo` animation will work. What is the most CSS oriented solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this use case, I'd suggest using a [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/transition) on hover instead.

This way is easier than going with animation

```
#entering {
    transition: .5s ease;
}
#entering:hover {
   width: 500px;
   height: 100px;
}
```

full code:

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}
p {
  font-family: Sans-Serif;
  color:white;
}
#entering {
  transition: .5s ease;
  text-align: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: none;
  font-family: Times;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
 resize: none;
 overflow: hidden; 
}
#entering:hover {
   width: 500px;
   height: 100px;
}
#text {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id = "text">
<textarea id = "entering">SAMPLE
</textarea>
</div>
<p>An example of my project.</p>
```